Problems when install libmr “libmr.so not exist”
$ virtualenv venv && source venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r python/requirements.txt
$ pip install .
Update: libmr is now available on PyPI. To install the latest version, you can simply:

$ pip install libmr
Building a shared object

If you have Cython and NumPy already installed but you do not want to install LibMR into Python's path, you can simply build the module directly:

$ python setup.py build_ext -i
This will place 'libmr.so' into the current folder. You can import it directly:

$ file libmr.so
libmr.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ...
$ python

import libmr
mr = libmr.MR()
Now, move libmr.so into your project's folder, or add this path into your PYTHONPATH environment variable.

I have read the guidance when I try to install libMR，however when I excute "python setup.py build_ext -i" there is no "libmr.so" in my folder which made me upset. I was using conda virtual environment and I did it based on windows because I do not have Linux/mac.Could you please help me to solve this problem,thank you very much.
The link is "https://github.com/Vastlab/libMR"
I have read the guidance when I try to install libMR，however when I excute "python setup.py build_ext -i" there is no "libmr.so" in my folder which made me upset. I was using conda virtual environment and I did it based on windows because I do not have Linux/mac.Could you please help me to solve this problem,thank you very much. My python version is 3.7,without libmr.so,I can not keep on my project--reprodece code about open set recognition.
